# I am teaching myself to identify sequences (harmonic and melodic) in Bach Orchestral Suite No.3 Air

Tags: theory

[image]

I am using Bach's "Air" to identify melodic/ harmonic sequences. I started some of the first page and want to know if I am on the right track. IS the bass I labeled considered a sequence? I also seem to have trouble identifying harmonic sequences.

Thanks

Comment: "I also seem to have trouble identifying harmonic sequences": have you made a harmonic analysis?  The lack of any harmonic symbols in the image suggests that you haven't.  The first step in looking for harmonic sequences is identifying the harmonies.

Comment: thanks! When I complete my harmonic analysis, how will I identify if it is a harmonic sequence? Would it be the same way as identifying melodic sequences?

Comment: Basically, yes.  You look at the analysis and see whether any part of it meets the definition of a harmonic sequence.  If you're not sure what a harmonic sequence is, you might add that to the question or ask a separate question about it.

Comment: I suggest you start studying harmony the way other people do, with something more homophonic, and a helpful book.  You could also take a class (or audit for free) a music theory class at your local community college, if you live in the US.